# Im thinking of buying a Nikon D610 do i need to get a specific lens for it to auto focus

Tags: lens, nikon

Im thinking of buying a Nikon D610 do i need to get a specific lens for it to auto focus? I know Nikon do various lens mounts but not sure which I need to look for

Comment: At the end of the user manual you can find a feature list for each type of lens. I think all the new lens(except a handful) can auto focus on D610s.

Answer (score 2):

D610 lens compatibility, from Nikon's website:

> AF NIKKOR lenses, including type G and D lenses (some restrictions
> apply to PC lenses) and DX lenses (using DX 24 x 16 1.5x image area),
> AI-P NIKKOR lenses, and non-CPU AI lenses (A and M modes only).
>
> IX NIKKOR lenses, lenses for the F3AF, and non-AI lenses cannot be used.

Comment: Some of those lenses can not autofocus on any camera. Not all of them are *fully* compatible in other ways, as well. They will "work" well enough to take a photo with the D610. But they may require manual focus and/or stop down metering or even external metering.

Answer (score 2):

F-mount lenses that are type AF, AF-I, AF-D, AF-S and AF-P should all autofocus with the D610.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure others will chime in with more comprehensive answers, but watch out for Nikon's latest mount/lenses – the "Z mount". Z-mount lenses are not compatible with the D610. The D610 uses the older F mount – those are the lenses you are looking for.